# Secure some Mysql tables from writing with chmod?

Tags: mysql, security, hosting, centos

Greeting Everyone

I have a linux box for hosting websites
I wanted to secure some tables from writing and modifying while the others is open for writing

so I came out with an idea to chmod some tables (MYD,MYI,frm) files in /var/lib/mysql/DATABASE

I need to ask if I can do so without breaking mysql database
and which permission I have to add to it?

thanks

Comment: why not use the RBDMS permissions? (i.e. using GRANT statements)

Comment: Bad idea. MySQL has different user accounts for this purpose. Create accounts that prohibit actions on certain tables and hand them out like that, never try to fiddle with MySQL internals from within O/S.

Comment: @N.B. Worth fleshing that comment out and posting as an answer?

Comment: @N.B. And how can I make user account that is prohibited to modify a table and allow to modify another table in the same DB

Comment: I meant RDBMS. Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: go to the table privileges section, I think thats what you are looking for   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you should use MySQL user accounts for such purpose. You can read more about user accounts at [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html), however I personally prefer GUI tools for this purpose. My personal favorite is [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) which lets you easily define per-table access level for a particular user (and more), especially if you're not familiar with MySQL command line.

Comment: actually I did try chmod 440 to the table files (MYD,MYI,frm) and it did well and fast

no if some one try to delete insert or edit a record it will not allow with mysql error and if i need to modify data I just chmod back to 660 and :D

Comment: And what happens if someone uses InnoDB engine?